# How to handle dependent beforeinserts in typeorm's entities

Tags: typescript, typeorm

In my `UserEntity` I have the following piece of code:

```
    @BeforeInsert()
    private async hashPassword(): Promise<void> {
        this.password = this.password ? await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10) : null;
    }

    @BeforeInsert()
    private async set2FAStatus(): Promise<void> {
        this.is2FA = !!this.password;
    }
```

As far as I understand, this is wrong, cos in theory the first function might well complete later then the second one and then the result won't be different than expected.

I know I could make these two operations inside one method, but apparently it would be a bad solution.

Comment: I would probably put them in one method. Also a warning about hashing passwords in @BeforeInsert: you might accidentally load the entity with the password, not set the password to plaintext, and then implicitly change the password to a double-hashed version next time you save the entity.

Comment: @RobertMoore Yeah I've arrived at the same conclusion. As for double-hashing, have already stumbled across this issue...

Comment: personally I just gave up using BeforeInsert because of the double-hashing problem, instead making passwordHash a separate field from the password field in the DTO. One thing I haven't tried is putting `{select: false}` on the password field @Column decorator so that it is never loaded from the database unless explicitly (in which case you must make sure to never save it that way). I wonder if that would solve the problem for you.